# How to get a list of all propriety name of a geoJson?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a geoJson file structured this way:

```
"type":"Feature",
         "id":"AFG",
         "properties":{
            "name":"Afghanistan"
         },
         "geometry":{
            "type":"Polygon",
            "coordinates":[
               [
                  [
                     61.210817,
                     35.650072
```

It's the whole world and I need to grab all the country names and have them as a list the following in order to be able to use them for the autocomplete:

```
var availableTags = [
"Afghanistan",
"Angola",
"Albania",
"United Arab Emirates",
    "Angola",
    "Albania",
    "United Arab Emirates",
    ....
```

How would I grab the country names as a list based on the geoJson object?

Comment: Have any link that can show whole geoJson object ?

Comment: @VivekDoshi sure thanks, there you go https://jsfiddle.net/td1ekts7/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here it is :

```
geoJson = //your geoJson Obj;    
var countries = [];
for(var k in geoJson.features) {
    countries.push(geoJson.features[k].properties.name);
}
console.log(countries);
```

Use `countries` as array for your autoComplete.

Comment: Then also will you please accept my answer? please.

Comment: Thanks you very much.

Answer (score 0):

```
var a = <YOUR GEOJSON>;
var countries = a.features.map(function (item) {
    return item.properties.name;
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Array#map()`

```
data.features.map(o=>o.properties.name)
```

here is your updated [JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/td1ekts7/1/)

Comment: i cannot see anything in the jsFiddle you linked am I missing something?

Comment: @rob.m Your JSfiddle is very slow to load

Comment: it's a whole world country geojson with all the polygons coordinates

Comment: when I open yours it says Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier